# Create method with varargs to permorf clicks

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to build up a method to permorfs clicks on WebElements, checkboxes specifically.
Scenario: I have aprox 15 checbox wich are used to grant roles and permissions to existing users in the system. Since i have to test the feature with all the possible variations, I think it would be more practical if i could create a method with varargs that permforms clicks depending on the args (Sorry, english is not my native)

Example: Let's say i have located all the checkboxes properly with names like (Strings) c1, c2, c3... etc. I would like to to do something like:

```
methodToPerformClick(c1) //so the method translates this to:
c1.click();

methodToPerformClick(c1,c7,c11) = so the method translates this to:
c1.click();
c7.click();
c11.click();
```

I know how to declare a methos with varargs but about managing diferent number of args.... I actually have no idea how to start, and since I don't now how to express my requirements properly in english to search them, it's really hard to find quality info over the internet in my own language. Any kind of help would be apprecciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah no. "Knowing something" isn't about "being able to write down the words". It is about *understanding* them. As in: varargs are a shortcut for *arrays*. That is all there is to this. And hint: it is a bad idea to build on weak fundaments. If your knowledge of basic java is so small, consider learning a bit more, before using it for real world tasks.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand how to iterate over the args, but I'm lost at the point to "convert" those Strings to "executable commands". Sorry for my bad expressions

Comment: That is a completely different question then. And sorry, you need to able to express your problem, otherwise we can't help. But: we also don't design solutions here. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) for example. We help with programming problems. We don't draw a map of the solution for you. You have to start with something yourself.

Comment: Also, I have been moved in my company from system related task to QA task, with no previous experience, so I can only learn DOING real world task and by my own. You right, I should learn more, i do it everyday. And you should stop judging people without knowing them. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Where did I judge you? I observed what you are doing, and I told you that this approach isn't efficient.